# Unknown Heroku Git Message Won't allow me to Push

Tags: django, git, heroku

I was configuring my Django code and db before deploying to heroku. After I push to Heroku via git, I get successfully installed messages, then it follows with this. Is it because I have an old dependency in requirements.txt?

```
remote:      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/app/hypetroopdjango/settings.py", line 147, in <module>
remote:            DATABASE['default'].update(db_from_env)
remote:        NameError: name 'DATABASE' is not define
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to warm-forest-32846.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/warm-forest-32846.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/warm-forest-32846.git'
```

Comment: In my settings.py i have `#replace database settings to use postgres on HEROKU
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASE['default'].update(db_from_env)
` to help with the postgress heroku db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have `DATABASES`! not `DATABASE`
smh